# Get data between StartDate & EndDate when dates available bewteen two days?

Tags: mysql

```
insert into mytable values
('100',     '2015-07-14',  '2015-07-25'), 
('200',     '2015-07-28',  '2015-07-30')
```

I need result like below when i search in the above table

example:

1. 2015-07-13 to 2015-07-29 (not available)
2. 2015-07-15 to 2015-07-22 (available)

I try like below query

```
select * from mytable where 
valid_from <= '2015-07-29' and valid_to >= '2015-07-13'
```

But it showing results is available.
Here Date's 13, 26, & 27 is not in the table.

Comment: What are the constraints you want to apply? Do you want to have both valid_from and valid_to between 2 given date?

Comment: valid from and to between 2 given dates

Comment: I've posted an answer - you just need to add some more constraints

Comment: 2015-07-13, 2015-07-26 & 2015-07-27 is not in the table

Comment: I don't think I understand what you need. Could you expand the question a bit? I can see you're inserting rows with 3 columns to the table. What are the columns? And what are the constraints that you want to apply? The sample query you provided suggests you want to find some dates within the range, what is the ooutput you exppect?

Comment: Ok, I think I misread your question. You'll need to reverse the constraints - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add some more constraints to the query:

```
select * from mytable where 
valid_to >= '2015-07-29' and valid_to <= '2015-07-13' and valid_from >= '2015-07-29' and valid_from <= '2015-07-13';
```

Comment: What are the columns in the insert query?

Comment: Rate, valid_from, valid_to

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
select * from mytable where 
(valid_to between '2015-07-29' and  '2015-07-13')
and 
(valid_from between  '2015-07-29' and  '2015-07-13');
```

and I suggest you to use date in UNIX time stamp (Epoch format).

Comment: in my table valid_from = 2015-07-14 and valid_to  = 2015-07-31. the above query not supporting

Comment: insert into mytable values
('100',     '2015-07-14',  '2015-07-31'), and i search between 2015-07-14 to 2015-07-29. its not supporting